# How to change an unintentional Community Wiki into a normal answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

I have accidentally turned one of my answers into a Community Wiki. What can I do turn it into a normal answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I converted [your answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/133917/41328) from Community Wiki to the standard answer.
This is something moderators can do (please flag your post for moderator attention in the future).

For more information see the duplicate question on the main Meta: [Is there a way to remove community wiki status?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974) Also, you may find [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) useful.